# asp.net webforms modules and handlers section - is remove required?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, iis-7.5, httpmodule, web.config-transform

Below is the default configuration for ASP.NET webforms web.config for specifying handlers and modules under IIS 7 (.5)

When you add custom modules and handlers, I would like to know if remove name ="custom module" is required before adding the module entry. I couldn't find much information on this on whether or why remove is required. I saw some examples where they didn't have removes.

The reason why I'm asking is I vaguely remember reading something about module references will keep adding same entries every time instead of having just one, eventually failing. But I can't find that anywhere now.

If someone can confirm, it will be much appreciated.

```
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  <modules>
    <remove name="ScriptModule" />
    <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  </modules>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
    <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory" />
    <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" />
    <remove name="ScriptResource" />
    <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode"
         type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode"
         type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look in the MSDN, but in the `<add>` [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d6sws33%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you will read this:

> The `<add>` directives are processed in top-down, sequential order. If
>   two or more `<add>` subdirectives specify the same verb/path
>   combination, the final  overrides all others.

Based on that, in order for a `<add>` directive to be overridden, it must have the same verb/path combination. If they do not match, both directives are active and that might cause conflict issues.

Removing the existing directives before declaring your own is a good practice to avoid any conflicts.

**Edit**: Your application inherits settings from other web.config files as well (See [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/the-configuration-system-in-iis-7) for more info). Those can be the `machine.config`, the root `web.config` etc. Those files can contain module and handler declarations as well. Adding `<remove>` helps you avoid any conflicts with those files.

Comment: but I'm not talking about having the same combination twice. If I have to add a custom module, do I need to specify remove first? I'll make sure it is only present once in the add section.

Comment: Adding remove before is just a *better safe than sorry* practice. If you are 100% sure that there is not a declaration with the same name to create a conflict then no, you don't need to remove it before adding it.

Comment: I updated my answer on why using `<remove>` is a good idea even if you declare your own custom handler only once.

Comment: what kind of conflicts are mentioning? do you know what will happen, will the application not work right away or eventually fail?

Comment: You actually can't know what will happen. Usually the application works and when it tries to use a handler that has a conflict it has an error or (not so common) it could work but with undesired behaviour.